# Removing items from collection while iterating IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, iteration, ienumerable

I have the following code:

```
foreach (var bar in dataFromDataFeed.Where(bar => bar.Key < fromTicks
                                                  || bar.Key > toTicks))
{
   dataFromDataFeed.Remove(bar.Key);
}
```

Is this safe or do I need to convert the IEnumerable within `foreach` to a `Dictionary<T,U>` first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that will either bomb or get you a result that still has bad elements.  Just invert the Where expression:

```
var filtered = dataFromDataFeed.Where(bar => bar.Key >= fromTicks && bar.Key <= toTicks);
dataFromFeed = filtered.ToList();   // optional
```

It isn't clear whether you actually need the list to be updated, often it is not necessary since you have a perfectly good enumerator, so the last statement is `// optional`.

Keep in mind that using Remove() like you did in your original code has O(n*m) complexity, *very* bad.  Using ToList() is only O(m) but requires O(m) storage.  Trading speed for memory is a common programmer's decision but this is a slamdunk unless m is huge (hundreds of millions and you're fighting OOM) or very small.  Neither should apply, given the expression.

Comment: thanks for the additional insight, I adjusted to avoid `Remove()`

Comment: Hmm, why did you select an answer that uses Remove?  It is a bad idea.

Comment: fair point, before answering, would you know whether inverting the expression or not makes a difference in terms of number of items iterated over, given that the source collection is sorted?

Comment: I selected the other answer originally because it came in first and addressed the question as I did not ask for the most optimal approach. But I appreciate the additional thought, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Matt - `Using Remove is bad idea` - That's completely dependent on collection items and size of the collection. So, I provided answer with posted content here. I appreciate Hans additional comments but those were never part of question. Anyhow selecting an answer is completely up to you. :)

Comment: @Rohit, he equally answered the question, just a little later. And I disagree with your last comment in that complexity does matter regardless of collection item type or collection size. It may sometimes be non-measurable but it will be more versatile to perform better on larger collections as well.

Comment: Yeah right. I have no issues with your choice of selecting an answer. I was just stating finding optimal solution was never part of question. Question was straight whether this code is safe or not. No problem mate..!!

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error because you are iterating over the collection. Modification of collection is not supported while you are enumerating over it.

Create new List using **`ToList()`**

```
foreach (var bar in dataFromDataFeed.Where(bar => bar.Key < fromTicks
                                         || bar.Key > toTicks).ToList())
{
   dataFromDataFeed.Remove(bar.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is considered bad practice to modify a collection while it is being enumerated, and in many cases this will cause an `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown.

You should copy the values into another List or array (e.g. by calling `ToList()` after your `Where()` call), and then you won't be modifying the original data.

```
foreach (var bar in dataFromDataFeed.Where(bar => bar.Key < fromTicks || bar.Key > toTicks).ToList())
{
    dataFromDataFeed.Remove(bar.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although `Dictionary` could almost certainly have included a method which would all a predicate function on each item and remove all items where that predicate returned true, it doesn't.  Consequently, if one has a `Dictionary` that includes some items which match a predicate and others which don't, the only ways to get a dictionary including only the items which don't satisfy the predicate are either to build a list of all the items satisfying the predicate and then remove from the dictionary all the items on the list, or else build a dictionary containing only items that don't satisfy the predicate and abandon the original in favor of the new one.  Which approach is better will depend upon the relative numbers of items to be kept and discarded.

As an alternative, one could switch to using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.  Unlike a `Dictionary`, a `ConcurrentDictionary` will allow items to be removed without invalidating any enumearation in progress.  If one only removes items as they are enumerated, I would expect a `ConcurrentDictionary` to enumerate exactly as one would expects.  If enumerating one item would sometimes cause code to delete a different item, then code must be prepared for the fact that removing an item which has not yet been enumerated might, *but is not required to*, cause that item to be omitted from the enumeration.

Although `Dictionary` is apt to generally be faster than `ConcurrentDictionary`, it may be worthwhile to use the latter if "delete items where..." operations are common and would have to either delete or copy a significant fraction of the items in the collection.